# What's the difference between ngBindTemplate and ngBind?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

According to the docs:

> The **`ngBind`** attribute tells Angular to replace the text content of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and to update the text content when the value of that expression changes.

and

> The **`ngBindTemplate`** directive specifies that the element text content should be replaced with the interpolation of the template in the ngBindTemplate attribute. Unlike ngBind, the ngBindTemplate can contain multiple {{ }} expressions. This directive is needed since some HTML elements (such as TITLE and OPTION) cannot contain SPAN elements.

My interpretation is that `ngBindTemplate` can do everything `ngBind` does, and more. So why do we even have `ngBind`?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [sources](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js#L109), ngBindTemplate involves $interpolate service, which:

> Compiles a string with markup into an interpolation function. This
>   service is used by the HTML $compile service for data binding.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't seem to answer my question. Why would one might use `ngBind` instead of `ngBindTemplate`?

Comment: Because it is faster. And in 90% of cases, I think, you don't need bind more then one value.

Answer (score 0):

A simple metaphor for the difference:

`ngBind` only runs "objects".

`ngBindTemplate` only runs "strings"